# How to perform element wise parallel matrix calculations in R?

Tags: r, matrix, parallel-processing

I've looked in vane for a solution to this, but I'm trying to find a method of splitting a matrix into sections and computing each section on a separate core of a node ( in Windows and/or Linux ).

I appreciate that a single matrix calculation will probably be slower in parallel due to latency etc, but my code has approximately 750 matrix calculations and takes approximately 12 seconds for a 3000*7000 matrix.

To make this reproducible, here is an example.

Lets say I have four matrices and a constant:

```
coln <- 7000
rown <- 3000

t    <- rown * coln

ecells <- matrix(runif(t,0,1),rown,coln)
scells <- matrix(runif(t,0,1),rown,coln)
wcells <- matrix(runif(t,0,1),rown,coln)
ncells <- matrix(runif(t,0,1),rown,coln)

aconstant <- 0.7
```

And then I calculate:

```
g <- ecells * scells * wcells * ncells *
     ecells * scells * wcells * ncells *
     ecells * scells * wcells * ncells *
     ecells * scells * wcells * ncells *
     aconstant
```

This takes approximately 1 second.

I can put this into **`Rcpp`** Armadillo and gain speed improvements:

```
sourceCpp(code= '#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

using namespace arma;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
mat moveC( mat ecells, mat scells, mat wcells, mat ncells, double aconstant ) {
  mat result = ecells % scells % wcells % ncells %
               ecells % scells % wcells % ncells %
               ecells % scells % wcells % ncells %
               ecells % scells % wcells % ncells *
               aconstant;
  return result;
}                                   
')
g <- moveC(ecells,scells,wcells,ncells,aconstant)
```

This takes approximately 0.4 seconds.

However, what I really want to do is to spread this across several cores and recombine the result, i.e. split the matrix across, lets say 4 cores for now ( i.e. the cores in my Windows desktop ) - which would require transferring of all the necessary data to perform the calculations.

Eventually, when my matrix gets large enough, I would like to do this by MPI, but I will save that for another day.

I know there are solutions utilising the `Parallel` package and possibly `RcppParallel`, or `OpenMP`, but I can only seem to find **`foreach`**-type examples and I really don't know how to implement what I want.

**Is it possible?**

Comment: Are you multiplying 750 times with only 4 matrices? Wouldn't be easier to use exponents?

Comment: **a)** Is the cell-wise structure of the 750 **`(.*)`**-ops identically repeating the access to the just `{e,s,w,n}`-matrices or is there another set of ~ 750 different matrices, having the shape of ~`[3k,7k]`? **b)** Are all of the said matrices content-protected / read-only or can any one of these become modified in-place? **c)** What is the target level of times in [us], you will consider a sought for solution to become sufficiently performance-tuned for your problem-domain?

Comment: A)There are loads of matrices, not 750 but a lot of different ones. I'm just using the e, w, s, n as an example. I want to understand how it could work in a simple case before trying to apply to my code (hundreds of lines). One thing in common however is that they are all 3000*7000. B) they can all be modified in place. C) it currently takes about 12 seconds per cycle. 2 or so would be great. My example is just so somebody could show me how to split multiple matrices and get each split set onto a slave node. Thanks.

Comment: "... **B)** ... 2 `[us]` or so would be great" ????? Ok, then this is **best to ask some clairvoyant** to make all that in just about 2 `[us]`. **Even the largest and fastest Quantum Computer will not be able to sniff out the ~ `16E+9` op-s on ~126 GB of `float64` data in just about 2000 `[ns]`**. At least not in any foreseeable future in our type of Universe.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you asked for it in seconds. - hence I meant 2 seconds or so. Did you mean micro seconds when you asked for it in us?

Comment: I guess on a four core machine I would imagine a quarter of the matrix would take about a quarter of the time, okay maybe 3 seconds plus some communication latency time. On a 12 core.or more much more. The important thing at this stage is not the speed up, I just want to be able to do it and see what it gives me. Many thanks and apologies for my misunderstanding of your request.

Comment: As far as I can tell you are doing effectively dot product operations which go as O(n). This is memory bandwidth bound. It will only scale with the number of sockets (i.e. scale with the number of independent memory controllers), but not the number of cores. You might see some improvement using multiple cores because it is difficult to saturate the memory bandwidth but at most a factor of 2 improvement. You need a O(n^3) operations such as matrix multiplication if you want it to scale with the number of cores but O(n^2) and O(n) don't.

Comment: I mean you are doing element wise operations c[i] = a[i]*b[i] which go as O(n) not the dot product (which also goes as O(n)).

Comment: Hi, to be honest with you I really don't understand your reply aboutt O(n). I would just like to know how to do it and worry about the improvement in performance later.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have 4 cores it's not worth the effort but here's how you would go about it. First you need to decide how to split up the operation into iterations. This is how I decided to do it

```
g <- ecells * scells * wcells * ncells *    # iteration 1
     ecells * scells * wcells * ncells *    # iteration 2
     ecells * scells * wcells * ncells *    # iteration 3
     ecells * scells * wcells * ncells *    # iteration 4
     aconstant
```

Then try

```
library(parallel)
cl <- makeCluster(4) # use makeCluster(detectCores()) to be general
clusterExport(cl, c("ecells", "scells", "wcells", "ncells")) # export your variables
parresult <- parLapply(cl, 1:4, function(x) ecells * scells * wcells * ncells) # performs this 4 times
```

This will result in a list (length 4) of a matrices equaling `ecells * scells * wcells* ncells*`. Combine them into a single matrix with `Reduce`, and multiply the constant

```
test <- Reduce("*", parresult) * aconstant
stopCluster(cl)
```

I get the same result with the parallel version as the vectorized version

```
all.equal(test, g)
[1] TRUE
```